# Will those if statements be resolved at compile time?

Tags: c++

Hey guys I have few questions that I can`t answer by my self.

```
void someFunc_1(some_known_type_1 bar);
void someFunc_2(some_known_type_2 bar);
void someFunc_3(some_known_type_3 bar);

template < class T, T success> 
void foo(T check) {

    // ...

    auto bar = check;

    if (std::is_same<T, some_known_type_1>::value) {
        someFunc_1((some_known_type_1) bar);
        // ... 
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, some_known_type_2>::value) {
        someFunc_2((some_known_type_2) bar);
        // ... 
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, some_known_type_3>::value) {
        someFunc_3((some_known_type_3) bar);
        // ... 
    }

    // ...
}
```

Code above is a simplest version of my template function to recognize // handle errors. I write this function in that way to avoid code duplication - if I have to use template specialization, I would find that in every version part of the code is repeated.

**Questions:** 
 1. Will those if statements be resolved at compile time? I think they will be but I am not sure. Code is compiling i tested it. 
 2. Normal if I did not use variable `auto bar` I would end up with compile time errors (type mismatch) for each if statement. **Therefore using `auto` variable is a good idea? Or Is there a better one?** (I tried also with function pointers, it worked, but it wasn't performance friendly)






**EDIT:** 
1. Ok so many of you told me that i could overload `someFunc`, so I done that. but I have new question now: **Is it wise to call empty void function?**

**New Version of the code**

```
///////////////////////////////////
// someFunc:
// - this function in my original code handles different kinds of errors.
// - overloaded for 2 different types (some_known_type_1 & some_known_type_2).
// - with "Catch-all do-nothing" template. 
inline void someFunc (some_known_type_1 bar) {
    // Do something...
}

inline void someFunc (some_known_type_2 bar) {
    // Do something...
}

// Catch-all do-nothing:
template <class T>
inline void someFunc(const T& bar) { /* I am empty... */ };

///////////////////////////////////
// Errchk: (Error check)
template < class T, T success> inline
void errchk(T check) {
    if (check != success) {
        std::cout << "there was an error !!!" << std::endl;

        // Handle Error:
        someFunc( check );
    }
}

// Few additional macros to simplify call to errchk function:
#define ERRCHK_BOOL(_check)   errchk <bool, true> (_check);
#define ERRCHK_TYPE_1(_check) errchk <some_known_type_1, type_1_success_value> (_check);
#define ERRCHK_TYPE_2(_check) errchk <some_known_type_2, type_2_success_value> (_check);

///////////////////////////////////
// program main function:
int main() {
    bool error = false; // this value will be recognized as an error by errchk function;
    ERRCHK_BOOL(error);

    some_known_type_1 error_1 = type_1_error_value // same...
    ERRCHK_TYPE_1(error_1);

    some_known_type_2 error_2 = type_2_error_value // same...
    ERRCHK_TYPE_2(error_2);
}
```

Ok so if you look closely you will see that I did not overload `someFunc` for bool type, therefore each time I use `ERRCHK_BOOL(***);` I will be calling un-specialized version of `someFunc` template, and this is basically a call to an empty function. **Is it a good idea to call empty function?**

Comment: Just check the generated code?

Comment: Also what did you write instead of `auto bar`? `T bar` should compile just the same, `auto` only performs (compile-time) type inference, it does not create a dynamic type

Comment: And considering that you want to call different functions depending on the type of `T` I'm pretty sure that using overloaded functions instead of template would be a better solution

Comment: UnholySheep
I do not know assembler :C
If i do waht you said (don't use auto) I would end up with compile time errors. Even though only one branch of the code will be executed at time, each one must have valid types. I cannot pass to `void someFunc_1(some_known_type_1 bar)` type `some_known_type_2` variable as parameter.

Comment: The standard doesn't care, it doesn't operate in these terms. Nobody knows what compiler you are using, but any that is not able to optimise away constant checks probably won't survive for long in the marketplace.

Comment: ". I cannot pass to void someFunc_1(some_known_type_1 bar) type some_known_type_2 variable as parameter." It looks like you are missing the idea of overloading. You should not have `someFunc_{123}` but rather a set of overloaded functions all named just `someFunc`. If you need to handle types not served by the overload set, you add a catch-all do-nothing `template <class T> void someFunc(const T&){}` to the overload set.

Comment: I have updated my question so it will include advice of all of you.

Comment: @n.m. That is what I had in mind, but my eng skill are not as good as i would like them to be, therefore i did not express that in the correct way. Your `catch-all do-nothing` is basically the main idea behind my code update. But will i suffer any performance penalty for calling an empty function??

Comment: @n.m. shameful you did not post full answer i would chose it as best one.

Comment: "will i suffer any performance penalty for calling an empty function?" It should be inline, as most normal function templates. So it will likely be optimised away completely unless a full debug build is made.

Comment: Also specializing function templates is not a very good idea, use a plain overload instead.

Comment: @m.n. Ok I have updated my simplified version. I don't use any specializations of template. Just plain overload. Would you mind looking at example? One more time Thank you.

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 yes, calling an empty function is perfectly normal. Compiler will be able to inline it (and thus get rid of it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **C++17** you can use `constexpr if` to make sure;

If you don't have access to C++17, there are still some SFINAE tricks (e.g. you can overload your function on some dummy extra argument) that will do the job, but the chances are your `if` statements will be resolved at compile time anyway.

As for `auto bar` part, the question is a bit unclear. Using `auto` here seems completely normal, although it's exactly the same as `T bar`.

I have to say though that a simple template specialization could do the same job somewhat clearer perhaps:

```
void someFunc_1(some_known_type_1 bar);
void someFunc_2(some_known_type_2 bar);
void someFunc_3(some_known_type_3 bar);

template < class T, T success> 
    void foo(T check) {
        // ...
    }

template <some_known_type_1 success> 
    void foo<some_known_type_1, success>(some_known_type_1 check) {
         someFunc_1(check);
         // ... 
    }
```

Not clear from your code - `success` parameter is somewhat in the way - but perhaps even function overload will suffice (as others noted).

Comment: I would end up with compile time errors. Even though only one branch of the code will be executed at time, each one must have valid types. I cannot pass to void someFunc_1(some_known_type_1 bar) type some_known_type_2 variable as parameter.

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 I don't see how that call happens

Comment: sory I did not express this in more precise way... Question Update includes modified code with your advice included - template specialization. I ended up making template from `someFunc` and then specializing this template for some known types of errors.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing looks like manually recreating the function overload system. Let the compiler take the strain:

```
void someFunc(some_known_type_1 bar);
void someFunc(some_known_type_2 bar);
void someFunc(some_known_type_3 bar);

template < class T, T success> 
void foo(T check) {

    someFunc(check);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, done it. But what if in one case `someFunc` would be an empty function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because `T` and `some_known_type_1` are known at compile time, modern compilers will optimise the if statements away. The reason: they have been designed over the decades to detect dead code branches and eliminate them. If you don't enable any compiler optimisations, then the answer will be no for the same reasons.

Comment: Thank you. Answer i was looking for.
Right now I am doing the same thing but without `if` statements. I am using instead templates + template specialization.

Answer (score 0):

`auto` doesn't quite make sense in that context since you're dealing with generic code, use `T bar = check;` instead.

Your unused branches will likely be optimized (at least clang/gcc do it - check it online https://gcc.godbolt.org/), as others have noted `constexpr if` in the upcoming C++17 will be your first choice for such a compile-time task.

Final notice: by not having a full insight into your code I can't really say but from just that snippet it seems you're reinventing type overloading or template specialization. You should take a step back and consider the bigger picture.